# Node/Gulp failing (can't load gulp-sass) outside Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, visual-studio-2015, gulp-sass

We are setting up Gulp with our VS project. When running the tasks from the VS Task Runner, they work flawlessly, but from the command line, it's failing.

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "OurProject",
  "description": "OurProject",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/something.git"
  },
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-cached": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-coffee": "^2.3.1",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.2"
  }
}
```

Gulpfile.js (simplified):

```
var
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('scss-compile', function () {
    return gulp
        .src("./Web/css/**/*.scss")
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./Web/css"));
});
```

Visual Studio *claims* to be using this command line:

```
cmd.exe /c gulp -b "C:\AbsoluteProjectPath" --color --gulpfile "C:\AbsoluteProjectPath\Gulpfile.js" scss-compile
```

Which doesn't work if I try it, because it can't find Gulp. So, I changed the current directory to `C:\AbsoluteProjectPath` and ran:

```
cmd.exe /c node_modules\.bin\gulp -b "C:\AbsoluteProjectPath" --color --gulpfile "C:\AbsoluteProjectPath\Gulpfile.js" scss-compile
```

And I got the following:

```
C:\AbsoluteProjectPath\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\extensions.js:148
    throw new Error(['`libsass` bindings not found in ', binaryPath, '. Try re
          ^
Error: `libsass` bindings not found in C:\AbsoluteProjectPath\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-ia32-14\binding.node. Try reinstalling `node-sass`?
    at Object.sass.getBinaryPath (C:\AbsoluteProjectPath\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\extensions.js:148:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\AbsoluteProjectPaths\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:16:36)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\AbsoluteProjectPath\node_modules\gulp-sass\index.js:163:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
```

Now, that `win32-ia32-14` folder doesn't exist. There is a `win32-ia32-11` instead.

What might be happening here?

Comment: have you tried running it from node.js for windows, should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be Visual Studio using a different version of node.js that resolves to a different list of packages.